# Phaser: Set object variable

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, pixi.js

I have some objects in game and i want to set `isEmpty` variable for each of them like this:

```
var object1.isEmpty; 
if (object1.isEmpty == 0) {
   object1.alpha=0.5;
}
```

How can i do  this with Phaser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objects are Phaser Sprites, or anything that extends them, then you can use the built-in `data` property to store this:

```js
var bob = this.add.sprite(100, 200, 'textureName');
bob.data.isEmpty = true;

// ...

if (bob.data.isEmpty)
{
  // do something ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PixiJS & Phaser are using JavaScript, you can edit your objects like this:

`//set your isEmpty-Variable as an negative boolean:
var object1.isEmpty = false;`

For more information please check: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: For a better reference, try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) - see [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/) for reasoning...